# Usage of $\frac 1 {O(n)}$

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics

I found the question [Is it true that $\frac{1}{2^{\mathcal{O}(\log n )}} = \frac{1}{\mathcal{O}(n )}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4327286/11206). I never saw this kind of usage of the $O$ symbol.
I checked [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Big-ONotation.html) but did not find anything.

I asked both the questioner and the answerer for a reference of this usage but did not get a useful answer.
The answerer told me that the meaning of $f(x)=\frac 1 {O(x)}$ is that $\frac 1 {f(x)} = O(x)$. Of course one can define this this way. Maybe  a usage like $2^{O(x)}$ may be useful, but it can be expressed as '$O(c^x)$ for a $c$'. But $\frac 1 {O(x)}$ looks strange to me because usually the $O$-notation is used to express the limitation from above.
Here we say that $f(x)> \frac 1 {cx}$ if $x>c$, so this is a limitation downwards.

So my question: is such a usage of the $O$ symbol, where it is used for a limitation downwards, really used? Can you give me some references for this usage?